# What to try to get BigQuery to CAST BYTES to STRING?

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

BigQuery [Standard SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) suggests that BYTE fields can be coerced into STRINGS.

We have a byte field that is the result of SHA256 hashing a field using BigQuery itself.

We now want to coerce it to a STRING, yet when we run "CAST(field_name to STRING)" we get an error:

> Query Failed Error: Invalid cast of bytes to UTF8 string

What is preventing us from getting a string from this byte field? Is it surmountable? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: Are you using standard SQL or legacy?  About 95% of my issues with BigQuery lie in this area.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Standard SQL

Answer (score 19):

Below example should show you an idea

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT SHA256('abc') x
)
SELECT x, TO_BASE64(x)
FROM t
```

in short  - you can use TO_BASE64() for this

Answer (score 9):

If you want to see the "traditional" representation of the hash in String, you have to use **TO_HEX()** function.

```
WITH table AS (
 SELECT SHA256('abc') as bytes_field
)
SELECT bytes_field, TO_HEX(bytes_field) as string_field
FROM table
```

By default in the UI, BigQuery shows you the base64 representation but if you want to compare it with other sha256 function from other language, for example, you have to use TO_HEX()

Answer (score 3):

You can try SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING() function.

reference: [SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_convert_bytes_to_string)

Comment: This worked for me when ingesting a Parquet file into BigQuery that had a column with JSON type that was actually parsed into BigQuery as a BYTES column type.  This method allowed me to retrieve the original JSON.