# Is SHA2 in Redshift is equivalent to SHA256 in BigQuery?

Tags: hash, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to hashing data with `SHA2` with 256-bit value in Redshift but the result is different from `SHA256` in BigQuery. Not sure it can be used or not because my user is using BigQuery but my team is using Redshift.

Here is what I'm trying.

**BigQuery**

```
SELECT SHA256('testing')

z4DNiu1ILV0VJ9fccvzv+E5jJlkoSER9LcCw6H38mpA=
```

**Redshift**

```
SELECT SHA2('testing', 256)

Result: cf80cd8aed482d5d1527d7dc72fceff84e6326592848447d2dc0b0e87dfc9a90
```

Or please suggest which function should be used, thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49660829/7813005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely both are correct but they are being displayed in different formats.

The Redshift answer agrees with my computers calculation of sha256 but both of these are returning a hex string.  However BigQuery produces the result as a BYTES datatype (base64, I believe) - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions

You will need to convert the BigQuery output to the same encoding (type) to compare these - see [What to try to get BigQuery to CAST BYTES to STRING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660672/what-to-try-to-get-bigquery-to-cast-bytes-to-string)

Comment: Thanks, I just check the return data type and found that they are differences. User still want me to convert to 32 bytes (as the return data from Big Query) which I don't think there is a function provided in Redshift. Might need to use UDF :(

Comment: Yes, if you want the result as a base64 string (vs. a hex string) you will need to create an UDF.